# Python Complex Number Multiplication

Tags: python-2.7, vector, complex-numbers

This is my simplified class assignment:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class MyComplex(Vector):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return MyComplex(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag, 
                         self.imag*other.real + self.real*other.imag)

    def __str__(self):
         return '(%g, %g)' % (self.real, self.imag)

u = MyComplex(2, -1)
v = MyComplex(1, 2)

print u * v
```

This is the output:

```
"test1.py", line 17, in <module>
     print u * v
"test1.py", line 9, in __mul__
return MyComplex(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag, 
                 self.imag*other.real + self.real*other.imag)
AttributeError: 'MyComplex' object has no attribute 'real'
```

The error is clear, but I failed to figure it out, your assistance please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change the constructor in Vector class to the following:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.real = x
        self.imag = y
```

The problem with your program was that it defined `x` and `y` as attributes, not `real` and `imag`, in the constructor for `Vector` class.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you have forgotten your initializer. As such, instances of `MyComplex` do not have any attributes (including `real` or `imag`). Simply adding an initializer to `MyComplex` will solve your problem.

```
def __init__(self, real, imag):
    self.real = real
    self.imag = imag
```

Comment: It should also be pointed out that by doing so you circumvent the need for `MyComplex` to inherit from `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
...
return MyComplex(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag, 
                     self.imag*other.real + self.real*other.imag)
...
AttributeError: 'MyComplex' object has no attribute 'real'
```

You have not attribute 'real' and 'imag' in your __init__ function. You should replace self.x, self.y attribute with self.real and self.imag.